# HTTP server error when changing tag preferences

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

When I click on the little star to include or exclude the "mysql" tag, it does nothing and the ajax call generates a server error. Other tags seem to work though, so it seems to be that particular tag that has a problem.

[image]

By the way, although both "mysql" and "php" are in favorite tags, the question is grayed out, which perhaps is a related bug.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: I believe you will find that you have [tag:mysql] in both your favourite **and** ignored tags. Remove it from one (or both) of these to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks that's indeed the case. But then that brings two more questions :) How did I manage to put the tags in both places? And shouldn't the popup be fixed to update the tags to match the star state?

Comment: I am looking into it - I don't think there is anything to stop one from putting a tag in both places, which would cause the weirdness with the star.

Answer (score 3):

This has happened because you had the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag in both your ignored and favourite tags lists (which can happen as a result of a merge).

When trying to toggle the state of a tag via the star on the tag hover card, this state of affairs hit a unique constraint in SQL Server, causing the 500.

To resolve the issue - remove the tag from one of the lists...

---

Given the easy workaround and how rare (and low impact) this state of affairs is, we will not be fixing the bug.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. It's a bit disappointing that SE would leave a 500 error unfixed, but I guess you have your reasons.

Comment: @this.lau_ - there are feature requests to work on, other bugs (with higher priorities and no workaround) - combined with limited resources. Need to pick our battles.